# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in E:\xampp\htdocs\bidding\header.php on line 15

Tags: php, debugging

Below is the code of

> header.php

This file is included in another file, by

> require 'header.php';

.

```
   <?php
    if(empty($user))
    { 
    $html=<<<eod
    <div class="account"><a href="publish.php">Post Task</a>  | <span class="boldfont"> $user</span> | <a href="../common/logout.php">Sign Out</a></div>
    eod;
    echo $html;
    }
    else { 
    $html=<<<eod
        <div class="account"><a href="../common/login.php">Sign in</a></div>
    eod;
    echo $html;
    ?>
    <a href="index.php"><img src="../common/logo.jpg" alt="Tenxian Logo" border=0 /></a>
```

However, I get an error message

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   $end in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\bidding\header.php on
>   line 15

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

think you need to properly close that `else {`

```
else { 
$html=<<<eod
    <div class="account"><a href="../common/login.php">Sign in</a></div>
eod;
echo $html;
} // <--- is missing
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule with PHP, 'unexpected end' means you go back and look for an unclosed block.

A `{` is not matched by a `}`